# Installing github.com/rogpeppe/godef FAILED

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I use Go: Install/Update Tools in VSCode to install `gocode` and `godef` but I get this error :

> Installing github.com/stamblerre/gocode FAILED Installing
>   github.com/rogpeppe/godef FAILED

and in the output ->

> ""D:\Krittawat\Learn\GoWorkspace\src\github.com\stamblerre\gocode"
>   is not using a known version control system" and 
>   ""D:\Krittawat\Learn\GoWorkspace\src\github.com\stamblerre\gocode"
>   is not using a known version control system"

I check my GOPATH GOROOT GOBIN by using "go env" 
and this is my GOPATH GOROOT and GOBIN

```
set GOPATH=D:\Krittawat\Learn\GoWorkspace
set GOROOT=D:\Krittawat\Programs\go1.12.7.windows-amd64\go
set GOBIN=
```

I don't know how to solve it. I searching for solutions, but nothing works.

Comment: `GOBIN` should normally be empty. (https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment or https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Environment_variables)

Comment: thx then how to solve this I try to delete github and golang.org and reinstall it but it still have same prob